# Rewrite subfolder only (HTTP to HTTPS) redirects to site root

Tags: redirect, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to rewrite HTTP to HTTPS for a specific subfolder on my IIS 8.5 web server but it's not working. I've read countless other solutions and blog postings but nothing I've tried works.

http://domain.example.com/one/two/three/
should redirect to... (same url but using https)
https://domain.example.com/one/two/three/

but instead is redirecting to... (site root using https)
https://domain.example.com

loading... (desired url with https)
https://domain.example.com/one/two/three/
also redirects to... (site root using https)
https://domain.example.com

it's removing the subfolders from the url.

This folder needs to also be protected with Windows Authentication, which I can get to work but the https redirection is failing with or without the authentication enabled so I don't think that's the cause.

Within IIS I selected the desired subfolder (/three/ in the example above) and created the Rewrite rule there.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="SeeOther" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This should of course work with any files and folders contained within the desired subfolder. (/three)

I tried this and it redirects to the apparent correct url but gives the "too many redirects" error:

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid doing this:

> Within IIS I selected the desired subfolder (/three/ in the example
>   above) and created the Rewrite rule there.

Instead setup the rewrite rules in `Web.config` at the application root.  You can redirect a specific folder to HTTPS by including it in the `match` parameter as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect Subfolder" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^one/two/three/" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Please note that this is a minimal `Web.config` file that does what you are looking for.  If your application already contains a `Web.config` in the root folder, then you will have to merge the above into your solution.